# Filter an array of Objects into Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to convert these following inputs into output.

Input:

```
[{"id":1, "subid":5}, 
{"id":1, "subid":9}, 
{"id":2, "subid":16}, 
{"id":2, "subid":27}]
```

Output:

```
[{1:[5,9]},
{2:[16,27]}]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var newobj = new Object(); 
listOfObject.forEach(function(i) { 
   var id = i.id 
   newobj[id] = [] 
   newobj[id].push(i.subid) 
   return newobj 
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce the data like this:

```
var arrayData = [{"id":1, "subid":5}, {"id":1, "subid":9}, {"id":2, "subid":16}, {"id":2, "subid":27}];

var result = arrayData.reduce(function (result, obj) {
  var id = obj.id;
  result[id] = (result[id] || []);
  result[id].push(obj.subid);
  return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Underscore utilities are quite handy for array and object manipulations. Try this:

```
var list = [{"id":1, "subid":5}, {"id":1,"subid":9},{"id":2,"subid":16}{"id":2, "subid":27}]   
 _.mapObject(_.groupBy(list, 'id'), function(val){          
       return val.map(function(obj){    
          return obj.subid
       })       
 })
```

Comment: Love it. More than my own answer. I'll switch to underscore utilities :)

Comment: @vivekmaharajh Also check out lodash.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = [
    {"id":1, "subid":5}, 
    {"id":1, "subid":9}, 
    {"id":2, "subid":16}, 
    {"id":2, "subid":27}
];

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var id = input[i].id;
  var subid = input[i].subid;
  if (output[id] == null) {
    output[id] = [];
  }
  output[id].push(subid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d just iterate through the input array and check for the existence of an existing property, then add a new object or push to the existing array.

```js
var input = [
  {"id":1, "subid":5}, 
  {"id":1, "subid":9}, 
  {"id":2, "subid":16}, 
  {"id":2, "subid":27}
];

var output = [];

input.forEach(function(a){
  var existing = output.find(function(b){
      return b.hasOwnProperty(a.id);
    });
  existing
    ? existing[a.id].push(a.subid)
    : output.push({[a.id]: [a.subid]});
});

console.log(output);
```